# React Router - abort transition in onEnter hook

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browserify

I'm using the latest version of react router (^3.0.0).

I'm trying to abort a transition in one of my components using the onEnter hook:

```
var AuthorPage = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    onEnter: function(nextState, replace, callback) {
        replace('/');;
        //hashHistory.replace('/');
    }},...
```

When I use the replace method of the onEnter hook it works fine (the component does change back to my main app component) but the URL remains the same : 
http://localhost:9005/#/authors instead of http://localhost:9005/#.

On the other hand when I use the hashHistory.replace method both the component and the URL change correctly (using the hashHistory of react-router).

There are two things I want to clarify:

1. Why would I want to use the replace method if it doesn't change my URL while it does changes the component back to what I want?
2. Is the hashHistory.replace method considered to be an appropriate way to perform the abort transition to a specific page?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `replace`. Using `hashHistory` won't interrupt the transition properly.

You'll need to do a little bit more digging to determine why it isn't updating the URL. It should be. If you can find this function:

https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/v2.x/modules/createHashHistory.js#L93-L123

in your `node_modules/history/createHashHistory.js` (it will be in ES5) you can try logging the location that you receive in there.

If that isn't called, you can try checking the `redirectLocation` value of the `match` callback in the `historyListener`.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/6eeb7ad358f987520f5b519e48bdd31f725cbade/modules/createTransitionManager.js#L212-L233